# Can you reverse a git push?

Tags: git, github

I have made a git add, commit and then the push. Can I revert the commit back to staging and remove feature/ticket-number from Github as this was added to Github after the push?

This is what I ran:
git commit -a -m "message here"
git push --set-upstream origin feature/ticket-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important part of version control if the ability to go back to a previous version: `git checkout HEAD~1` will checkout the commit before this last one. `git push origin feature/ticket-number -f` will force this to be the new state of your feature.